# can you connect a wired controller through a pc to an android without plugging it into the tablet itself

Tags: game-controllers

i say this because i dont have an usb otg cable or whatever its called and i dont want to go out and buy one

Comment: So you want to connect a wired control to a PC, then have it control things on an Android device? I don't really see how that would be possible. Just order an OTG cable, they are dirt cheap, pretty sure I ordered a bag of 5 of them for like $3 on eBay.

Answer (score 0):

some applications are made to interconnect an android device and a personal computer for casting or to make the android device do the job of a mouse for example. but your way is impossible because there hasn't been any software which allows a device to connect to android through PC and the fact is there is no need for it. or else nobody has developed a software for it. 
better u buy it from amazon. its cheap nowadays

Answer (score 0):

Just download BlueStacks on PC and map PC keys to touch screen
Next download pinnacle controller and map PC keys to controller
Problem solved (: